# EPPlus load custom value

Tags: c#, epplus

I have cell which contains value

```
7.11.2014
```

in custom format

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

so in excel it looks like

```
07/11/2014
```

when i load it via EPPLus

```
cellValue = sheet.Cells[row, column].Value.ToString();
```

it loads the General format value, which is

```
41950
```

How can i load the Value `07/11/2014` or other date format with i can work ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand, how exactly `41950` is a general format of `07/11/2014`?

Comment: 41950 is the number of days since Excel's epoch date of 1/1/1900

Comment: @IronMan84 Are you sure? `var dt = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1); return (DateTime.Now - dt).Days;` returns `41948` not `41950`.

Comment: It includes both dates in it for some reason. Either way `DateTime.Parse()` parses out the correct date for me in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i got it, this code works

```
long serialDate = long.Parse(sheet.Cells[r, c].Value.ToString());
cellValue = DateTime.FromOADate(serialDate).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking over some similar code that I've done before, all you'll need to do is to use `DateTime.Parse()` and it should come out exactly how you want it.

As I mentioned in the comments Excel saves the actual dates as being a number of days from its epoch date of 1/1/1900 (hence why you keep seeing 41950). .NET code will accept that, and will convert it to the correct date.